# How to move a file from the staging area to the working tree in Git?

Tags: git, staging

For example, I have a file called `test1.txt` in my local folder. I've added it to the staging area using `git add -A`. Now how can I move `test1.txt` from the staging area to the working tree?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by move to "the working directory". Is it not in the same working `git` directory?

Comment: It's the local directory, from which it's been moved to staging aread

Comment: Git calls this the *working tree* (in early versions of Git, Git called it both "working tree" and "working directory"). I updated the question text to match modern usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me was:

```
git restore --worktree test1.txt
```

I mean, trying to clarify:

1. **Step 1**: I write a new file test1.txt with the following content:

> This is test1.txt first content

2. **Step 2**: I execute *git add test1.txt*. Now this first content of test1.txt is *staged*.
3. **Step 3**: I modify test1.txt, with the following content:

> This is test1.txt first content.
> And now this is new content

Now there is modified content in test1.txt in the *working tree* that differs from the content of test1.txt in *staging*.

4. **Step 4**: I want to discard last changes of test1.txt in my working tree and recover the content of test1.txt from the staging. So I execute the following:

   git restore --worktree test1.txt

Now I can see that test1.txt has only the first content, the one that I staged in Step 2.
If I used --staged flag it wouldn't restore the content of test1.txt.

Answer (score 3):

Use `git restore --staged test1.txt` to move back the file from *stage area* to *working directory*.

This command is also see, if you run `git status` and you have files in the *staging area*.

As example:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
     modified:   test1.txt
```

If you are not familiar with the *basic* Git commands, have a look at this overall-picture:

[image]

Comment: So if I do "git reset fileName", according to the picture it'll be moved back to the working directory from staging right?

Comment: Yes exactly, but I prefer for this what you want `git restore`. The difference between `git restore` and `git reset`, you can read in this [article](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_reset_restore_and_revert)